# Communication between VS extension and user controls in design mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls, design-time, extensibility

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension along with a WPF user control library that will be included in the VSIX package. I have an interesting requirement that involves providing data to my user controls during design mode. I'm looking for a way for my user controls to access resources that are initialized in my `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package` class.

I initially attempted using a singleton class to share the resources. Obviously, this didn't work because the VS package and the design-time user controls are running in separate app domains. My next idea was to use IPC such as a memory-mapped file to share the data. I would like to avoid this if possible.

I should mention that my user controls have custom `PropertyValueEditor` classes for certain properties, and my end goal is to modify the WPF data templates for these based on information contained in my VS package.

Anyways, my question is:
**are there any good ways for my user controls to access data contained in my VS package while running in design mode?**

Comment: did you ever get this working?